# Compute the sum $\sum_{k\ge0}{k \choose n-k}(-1)^k.$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Compute the sum

$$\sum_{k\ge0}{k \choose n-k}(-1)^k.$$

At this point I have tried many binomial theorem identities to try and get something to happen with the $n-k$, but couldn't seem to make sense of it.  I also tried to form a recursive relation, but also couldn't seem to get it in the right form to where I could solve the relation.

Comment: What is $m$ in $\binom k{m-k}$?

Comment: I think your summation over $k$ should be less than $m$ in order to make sense.

Comment: The substitution $q = m-k$ will transform this sum into the one treated at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256143/) (times a factor).

Comment: Following the convention that $ {m \choose n} = 0$ when $n < 0$, @MarkoRiedel's link should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer (in that it is more of an evidence based conjecture than a proof).

I wrote a python script to calculate the sum for values of $m$ in the range $m=1..1000$ and the following is always true:

$$\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{k}{m-k}(-1)^{k} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if }m\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\ -1 & \text{ if }m\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\ 0 & \text{ if }m\equiv 2 \pmod 3\end{cases}$$

At the moment I am at a loss to prove this, but perhaps, knowing the answer will allow a proof to be made.

This of course uses the conventions that $\binom{0}{0}=1$ and $\binom{a}{b}=0$ if $b>a$ or if $b<0$.  Because of all the "zero" cases, it only makes sense to sum values of $k$ for which $k\leq m\leq 2k$.  This allows you to make the sum from $k=\lceil\frac{m}{2}\rceil$ to $k=m$.